# How to migrate a blog from Wordpress to Wordpress Mu

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to migrate some old blogs to Wordpress Mu. I've seen the solutions that suggest renaming some tables, which I'm fine doing, but I feel like there needs to be a real tool out there for this purpose.

Do you know about one?

If not, any "gotchas" for the table-renaming method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that "WordPress MU" was merged into the WordPress 3.0 release, and is now known as "[WordPress Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)."

I recommend doing using the built-in export/import, but that does require you to migrate plugin and some other settings manually. In my opinion, this will provide you with the cleanest path to a 3.0 network.

Comment: I installed WordPress Mu 3.0.1. Can I assume this is Wordpress 3.0 with networks already turned on?

Comment: The [WordPress MU homepage](http://mu.wordpress.org/) just points to WordPress, as of the 3.0 release. I don't know what "WordPress MU 3.0.1" would be, given that. (Sounds sketchy.)